# Possible to infer type used within a generic interface of a parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, inference, inferred-type

I have this method:

```
attachTheme<TTheme, TSelector>(config: IConfig<TTheme, TSelector>): OtherClass<TSelector> {
}
```

IConfig:

```
interface IConfig<TTheme, TSelector> {
    select(theme: TTheme): TSelector;
}
```

I would like to use it in this way:

```
attachTheme<MyTheme>({ select: theme => ({ background: theme.scroller.background }) });
```

With the return value being typed with `{ background: string; }` but if I don't specify the TSelector with a default, it complains, so if I put `{}` as a default, the outputted generic type is `{}`, even though I feel it should infer the type.

I've looked into the `infer` keyword, but can't get it to work, I feel like I don't understand it well enough to use it in the right way and I was hoping someone would understand it better than I enough to solve my issue?  There seems to be very little about the keyword and fewer examples of how it can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to let the compiler infer both parameters by specifying the theme as a type annotation to the arrow function parameter

```
attachTheme({ select: (theme: MyTheme) => ({ background: theme.scroller.background }) });
```

If you don't want to do this in 3.1 we will get  [Named type arguments & partial type argument inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23696)

The other solution is to use a function returning a function to be able to specify one argument and lent inference take care of the other one .

```
function attachTheme<TTheme>() {
    return function <TSelector>(config: IConfig<TTheme, TSelector>): OtherClass<TSelector> {
        return null;
    }
}

attachTheme<MyTheme>()({ select: theme => ({ background: theme.scroller.background }) });
```